# Populate TextBox with Text from DataTable - Combo Box

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf

I have a Data Table (Two DataTables but we will just imagine there is one for now) that have been declared when my window loads, this DataTable is populated with:

- NoteID
- NoteName
- Note

**NoteID:** The First Column in my SQL Database giving the Note and ID

**NoteName:** The Second Column in my SQL Database giving the note a Name

**Note:** This is the third and final column giving the note its Text (Could be quite long its a VarChar(MAX))

Currently my DataTable populates no problem, however i want to fill my TextBox(Named: textResult) with the "*Note*" column associated with the "NoteName" that is selected in the Combo Box.

```
//Setup connection to server
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = "123.123.123.123";
        builder.InitialCatalog = "DiscoverThePlanet";
        builder.UserID = "TestPerm";
        builder.Password = "Test321";

        string connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;

        DataTable dtNotes = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtTemplateNotes = new DataTable();


        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmdNotes = new SqlCommand("SELECT NoteID, NoteName, Note FROM Notes", conn);
            SqlCommand cmdTemplateNotes = new SqlCommand("SELECT TemplateNoteID, TemplateNoteName, TemplateNote FROM TemplateNotes", conn);

            SqlDataReader readerNotes = cmdNotes.ExecuteReader();

            dtNotes.Columns.Add("NoteID", typeof(string));
            dtNotes.Columns.Add("NoteName", typeof(string));
            dtNotes.Columns.Add("Note", typeof(string));
            dtNotes.Load(readerNotes);

            SqlDataReader readerTemplateNotes = cmdTemplateNotes.ExecuteReader();

            dtTemplateNotes.Columns.Add("TemplateNoteID", typeof(string));
            dtTemplateNotes.Columns.Add("TemplateNoteName", typeof(string));
            dtTemplateNotes.Columns.Add("TemplateNote", typeof(string));
            dtTemplateNotes.Load(readerTemplateNotes);

            // Temporary loop to see if the DataTable (dt) has any data?!?
            //foreach (DataRow thisRow in dt.Rows)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show(thisRow["NoteName"].ToString());
            //}

            // Define the columns BEFORE setting the item source
            noteNamesList.SelectedValuePath = "NoteID";
            noteNamesList.DisplayMemberPath = "NoteName";

            templateNoteNamesList.SelectedValuePath = "TemplateNoteID";
            templateNoteNamesList.DisplayMemberPath = "TemplateNoteName";

            // Set the ItemSource to my fully loaded data table!
            noteNamesList.ItemsSource = dtNotes.DefaultView;
            templateNoteNamesList.ItemsSource = dtTemplateNotes.DefaultView;

            //DEBUG START
            //MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            //DEBUG END

            conn.Close();
        }
```

Like is said i have to different Drop Downs but lets just use the one called "*dtNotes*" for now

I'm pretty new to this and if i try and reference "*dtNotes*" anywhere in my code it can't find it?

My *textResult* XAML if you need it:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="760" Margin="42,141,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1494" AcceptsReturn="True" TextChanged="textResult_TextChanged" BorderBrush="#FF00A9CF" FontFamily="DengXian" FontSize="14.667" Background="#FFF3FFFE" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

Combo Box if you need it:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="noteNamesList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="42,101,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" BorderBrush="White" Opacity="0.985" FontFamily="DengXian" FontSize="13.333"></ComboBox>
```

Hopefully i have provided enough information for you, any help is much appreciated.

PS This is on WPF

Comment: Which platform are you working with that uses Xaml?

Comment: Oh forgot to mention this is WPF, is that what you mean? @Takarii

Comment: You should be able to simply use the `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` event and within that use the `TextBox.Text = ComboBox.SelectedValue` method. Keep in mind, if your datatables are local (ie, within a specific method) you won't be able to reference them in any other method. You need to move the DataTable declaration to be class wide. Your snippet suggests this could be a possability

Comment: @Takarii ah ok, thanks for the comment, so where my DataTables are at the moment is that local then? How do i make them non local?

Comment: in the area between the namespace and the constructor, place them there

Comment: You should really read up about [MVVM  Patter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx), this tight coupling of your presentation layer, model and Data Access Layer is not a great idea. You may also wish to use an ORM, to really trim down the amount of code needed. [Here is a very simple example](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html)

Comment: @GarethD These look really helpful, i'll take a look properly when im home, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might be declaring your datatables as local variables for that method.

Place the `DataTable` declaration in the space between `Namespace` declaration and the class constructor

```
Namespace MyProject
{
    public sealed partial class MyClass : Page
    {
        //Class wide variables go here

        DataTable mytable = new DataTable();

        class MyClass()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

After that you should be able to reference your `DataTable` within the `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` event to assign your value to the `TextBox`

Edit:

Within the `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` event use

```
TextBox.Text = ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

where `TextBox` is the name of the TextBox to assign to, and `ComboBox` is the name of the ComboBox you want to get the value from.

or, if like in your case, its a third value the combobox can't handle directly

```
TextBox.Text = DataTable.Rows[ComboBox.SelectedIndex]["Note"].ToString()
```

Comment: Ah brilliant this has already allowed me to use my datatables all over my code. Could you just give me a hand as to what to declare for the textbox. Would it be something like textResult.Text = noteNamesList.SelectedValue(dtNotes); where would i declare that i want the "Note" column from the datatable? Many Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm, the value for the textbox is the value specified within the combobox selection?

Comment: This prints the NoteID so like 1, 2, 3 so on, not the actual "Note"?

Comment: try using `TextBox.Text = DataTable.Rows[ComboBox.SelectedIndex]["Note"].ToString()`

Comment: Brilliant, sorted, Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You use of a complicated code for load data from sql table.
You can use `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` easily:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your Connection Settings");
string command="Select Note FROM Notes Where NoteName='" + comboNoteName.Text + "'";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command, conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

By this, DataTable is filled by Data and Data types as well as sql Table.
Now, fill the TextBox:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
   textResult.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Note"].ToString();
```

**Edit :**

You can use this too:
You can fill DataTable once in Form_Load event and use it frequently where is needed:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your Connection Settings");
string command="Select NoteId, NoteName, Note FROM Notes";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command, conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Now, in the ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged event put it:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    textResult.Text = dt.Select("NoteName='" + comboNoteName.Text + "'")[0]["Note"].ToString();
```

Comment: this doesn't resolve the problem being experienced. it also doesnt handle the fact that the selected value comes from a combobox.

Comment: In the line #2, comboNoteName is the mentioned ComboBox.

Comment: Keep in mind though, this would cause a new query to be sent to the database each time the selection is changed. While it may be small, i would certainly avoid sending any more requests than is needed

Comment: Ok. You'r right. But it is accessible too. See the edit.